# LoadLibrary failure: The network path was not found

Tags: r, rstudio, rtools

R studio hasn't been working for me, and the error:  `"LoadLibrary failure:  The network path was not found"`
keeps showing up. My libraries, packages and R studio are in the same folder.

Tried `.libpaths()`, put rtools in the same folder as R Studio

Comment: "My libraries, packages and R studio are in the same folder." That's very likely the problem.

Comment: Please be clear about this: Rtools should likely be in `C:\Rtools42`; R defaults to `C:\Program Files\R-4.2.3` I believe (or whatever version you're running); your library of personal packages should be `%APPDATA%\Local\R\win-library\4.2`. These should all be different, no overlap. Your projects (including `.R` files) should be in _none_ of those.

Comment: Can you run R outside of the RStudio IDE? Where are all of _your_ apps/programs installed?